# Merge video files and subtitles

Tags: video, merge, subtitle

I have some files

```
chapter1.mp4
chapter1.srt
chapter2.mp4
chapter2.srt
chapter3.mp4
chapter3.srt
```

I know how to merge the video files, but what about the subtitles, I dont want to hardcoded it to video. Is any away to merge and have the proper timing in a single .srt file ?

Comment: Using ffmpeg you can make a mkv container file which contains both the mp4 and the srt.

Comment: Hi @zakari. How do you go about merging the video files? Maybe your tool is able to merge srt as well… As Smile4ever mentioned, ffmpeg is a too which can do both, it's really powerful, but has a command line interface.

Comment: The `-itsoffset offset (input)` parameter sounds promising…

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).

While there might be a (complicated) way to concatenate the srt files first, the easiest way is to combine pairs of video and text first, and then concatenate the resulting container files.

1. Copy everything from chapter1.mp4 and add subtitles from chapter1.srt

```sh
# Assuming English for subtitle language
ffmpeg -i chapter1.mp4 -i chapter1.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=en -metadata:s:s:0 title=English chapter1-srt.mp4
```

`-c copy` will copy everything that might be in chapter1.mp4, and `-c:s mov_text` will format the text stream from chapter1.srt into subtitles for mp4 (mov_text). The result will be written to *chapter1-srt.mp4*.

2. Repeat the same command for chapters 2 and 3
3. Create a text file (f.e. chapters.txt) with the resulting file names

```
chapter1-srt.mp4
chapter2-srt.mp4
chapter3-srt.mp4
```

4. Concatenate the resulting container files listed in the text file

```sh
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i chapters.txt -c copy everything.mp4
```

See [ffmpeg's concatenate demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer)